# Attiny88 with Micronucleus: Flash write error -1 most of time

Tags: arduino, flash, attiny, error

I have this board with an Attiny88, a pin compatible Nano 'equivalent':

[image: MH-Tiny88]

I want to build a simple motor controller however most of the time when I upload a program I get this error:

```
Running Digispark Uploader...
Plug in device now... (will timeout in 60 seconds)
> Please plug in the device ... 
> Press CTRL+C to terminate the program.
> Device is found!
connecting: 16% complete
connecting: 22% complete
connecting: 28% complete
connecting: 33% complete
> Device has firmware version 2.2
> Device signature: 0x1e9311 
> Available space for user applications: 6650 bytes
> Suggested sleep time between sending pages: 7ms
> Whole page count: 208  page size: 32
> Erase function sleep duration: 1456ms
parsing: 50% complete
> Erasing the memory ...
erasing: 55% complete
erasing: 60% complete
erasing: 65% complete
>> Eep! Connection to device lost during erase! Not to worry
>> This happens on some computers - reconnecting...
>> Reconnected! Continuing upload sequence...
> Starting to upload ...
writing: 70% complete
>> Flash write error -1 has occured ...
>> Please unplug the device and restart the program.
```

This is very annoying. Is this a firmware problem or is this a hardware problem? I tried different cables, different USB ports and nothing helps. I have the latest IDE and firmware. What can I do to fix this problem? Anybody knows what to do?